# How to troubleshoot why event doesn't reach the target setup in the event bridge

Tags: c#, .net, aws-event-bridge, aws-sdk-net

I have two different aws accounts with similar environment AFAICT. I setup an event-bridge/rule/target in each environment. I used same event pattern in rule in both environments. I then setup separate admin user in each environments with same permissions. Following code works fine in one environment (meaning the event reaches the target) but doesn't work in the other environment. However, for the environment where it doesn't work, the code still returns a result.HttpStatusCode of OK.

```
string awsAccessKey = "whateveraccesskey"; 
string awsSecretKey = "whateversecretkey"; 
string awsEventBusName = "myEventBus"; 
string awsEventSourceName = "mySource"; 
Amazon.RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;  

AmazonEventBridgeClient ebClient = new AmazonEventBridgeClient(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, regionEndpoint);  
var eventRequestEntry = new PutEventsRequestEntry() 
{     
    DetailType = "Test Detail Type",     
    EventBusName = awsEventBusName,     
    Source = awsEventSourceName,     
    Detail = "Test Details",     
    Time = DateTime.Now 
};   

PutEventsResponse result = await ebClient.PutEventsAsync(new PutEventsRequest() 
{     
    Entries = new List<PutEventsRequestEntry>() { eventRequestEntry } 
}).ConfigureAwait(false);  
if (result != null) 
{     
    Console.WriteLine($"StatusCode {result.HttpStatusCode}"); 
} 
else 
{     
    Console.WriteLine("null result"); 
}
```

I am just not sure how to troubleshoot the code or that aws environment to determine why this event doesn't reach the target. Any hints or ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you see in the rule metrics that it matches/invokes the target? Is the event bus name/arn correct (you'll not get an error for publishing to a non-existent event bus)? You can also set up a dead-letter queue per target (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_Target.html#eventbridge-Type-Target-DeadLetterConfig) to capture any error (I recommend to set retries=0 so it will immediately DLQ events).

Comment: Rule metrics matching the event bus name and rule name doesn't show anything. I have a DLQ setup for the target queue but its also empty. As mentioned in the question, the same code works fine in one environment so it looks like some issue in the other environment and I am hoping aws provide tools to help troubleshoot these type of issues.

Comment: Similar to the recently introduced logging improvements to EventBridge Pipes (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-logging-support-for-amazon-eventbridge-pipes/) event buses will eventually also support enhanced logging to ease troubleshooting. Make sure the event bus name is correct because you won't get an error for publishing to a non-existing bus.